# Anisotropic version of scikit-fmm?

Tags: python

Can anyone point me to a Python package that can perform anisotropic fast marching, equivalent to the way `scikit-fmm` handles isotropic FM?

Comment: Editors: this is a rephrased and simplified version of a question I posted recently that was deemed 'too broad'. Bizarre but true. The topic of anisotropic fast marching is not a broad one even for mathematicians specializing in geometry.

Comment: `scikit-fmm` could probably be adapted to handle anisotropic fast marching. Can you give an example of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Jason, hi, and thanks both for writing `scikit-fmm` and for getting back to me here on this point. Very much appreciated.

Some of the applications I have in mind are where the speed of front motion depends on its orientation relative to gravity. I believe a Matsumoto-type Finsler metric describes such motion, e.g., Matsumoto 1989, J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 29-1: 'A slope of a mountain is a Finsler surface with respect to a time measure'.  

More generally I'm interested in FM with Finsler metrics. Jean-Marie Mirebeau has several papers on this topic. It's tougher than elliptical anisotropy!